# Cómo hago un forward en servlets 2.4 si fileUpload fue usado?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Necesito hacer un forward de un servlet a otro y pasarle la información del objeto request. El problema está en que en el primer servlet utilizo la librería FileUpload de Apache y algo le hace al request que no me deja mandárselo bien al siguiente servlet.

Si mandamos un formulario **SIN** *enctype="multipart/form-data"* podemos trabajar con los campos en el servlet de manera sencilla con `request.getParameter()` y hacer un forwar de la siguiente manera al otro servlet:

```
ServletContext context= getServletContext();
            RequestDispatcher rd= context.getRequestDispatcher("/mySegundoServlet");
            rd.forward(request, response);
```

Y en mySegundoServlet puedo volver a utilizar el objeto request de la misma manera que lo utilicé en el primer servlet.

PERO si yo tengo el *enctype="multipart/form-data"* porque lo necesito para mandar algún archivo, es necesario utilizar las librerías de FileUpload de apache, y todo bien; pero cómo le hago para mandar llamar a */mySegundoServlet* sin que se pierda la información del objeto request? o sea que para mi segundo servlet en este caso ya no necesito el FileInput, solo necesito la información que iba en el request de los campos input text comunes y corrientes del formulario. Si hago el forward como arriba, los objetos me llegan nulos a mi servlet. Y si en el primer servlet intento hacer un request.setAttribute de igual manera llegan nulos en el otro servlet.

Hay alguna forma de limpiar mi objeto request para resetearlo y volver a a setearle información con request.setAttribute? Porque por alguna razón siento que el problema está en que el request sí se pasa bien pero AMBOS servlet deben utilizar el parse del fileUpload porque en un principio el formulario se envió con *enctype="multipart/form-data"*

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Versión corta

Si estás procesando una carga/subida de archivo y vas a enviar el request de un servlet a otro mediante forward y necesitas obtener los parámetros del request en ambos servlets, estás limitado a usar Apache FileUpload.

### Más detalles

Sucede que al usar `enctype="multipart/form-data"` estás indicando al servidor que va a cambiar la forma cómo va a recibir los parámetros y cómo va a interpretarlos. Esto no es específico de Java, es parte de la [especificación de HTML 5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission-0) y el servidor web soporta este intercambio de datos.

Antes de Servlet 3.0, para procesar los formularios enviados con `enctype="multipart/form-data"` se usaba la librería Apache FileUpload, que bien mencionas. Esta librería aplica la conversión necesario de los parámetros del request para obtener las partes del request en forma de parámetros que puedes procesar, entre ellos los streams del o los archivos que soporta. Esto significa que, si vas a procesar este request por uno o más servlets, necesitarás **forzosamente** obtener las partes del request para acceder a los parámetros. Puesto que usas Servlets 2.4, solo lo puedes hacer mediante esta librería Apache FileUpload.

Comment: Y qué hay sobre maneras alternas? Se me ocurre por ejemplo crear un nuevo request y ese mandarlo por forward en vez del request que llegó, crees que es posible?

Comment: Podrías hacerlo, pero deberás crear alguna implementación particular de la interfaz o un mock y usar esta instancia con la información precisa. Esto es muy fácil de romper y brinda más problemas de mantenimiento. Puesto que no pones más detalles, quizás optaría por no usar forward. Por otro lado, no entiendo qué dificultad hay en usar Apache FileUpload en el segundo servlet. Si es porque este segundo servlet está siendo reusado por más de un tipo de request, podrías agregar un parámetro antes del forward que te indique cómo obtener los parámetros.

Comment: Opté por hacer el forward al servlet con la url completa, o sea pasándole los parámetros que ocupa el servlet principal para trabajar por get. No fue lo mejor en absoluto pero funcionó. El problema más que nada es que a la app se le llama desde el primer servlet por get, carga la info y luego el jsp, este jsp manda a llamar al segundo servlet que cuando hace su trabajo manda a llamar al primero. Entonces, se me hizo un poco laborioso andar validando en cada servlet si es multipart o no el request, ya que, como sabes, es diferente la manera en que se obtienen los parámetros del request